# A more "meta" logo?

Tags: discussion, meta, logo

I think that the Meta logo does not reflect its "meta" nature. What about something like that instead:

[image: sample 1]

Or

[image: sample 2]

or, as suggested by [random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random), something more [ouroboros](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46173/a-more-meta-logo#comment105930_46173) such as:

[image]

Any other ideas?

Comment: Needs more ouroboros.

Comment: Personally I don't like the greyscale site with the red / distressed "meta" in the logo.

Comment: The answer is obviously a stack of stacks.

Comment: no, the answer is a stack of itself

Comment: no!  a dishwasher!

Comment: Hahaha, **really @Pekka**?  =)

Comment: @jadarnel yeah, man! Meta's logo is way too boring, I've always thought so.

Comment: @JoshK there was much whining about the greyscale when "meta" first launched, but it's staying because Jeff likes it... it's kind of like  a "shadow" of the real site.

Comment: FWIW, I really like the 2nd image.

Comment: Gotta spend that meta rep on something, eh @Pekka :)

Comment: @Adam yeah, but I really believe in this cause! The current Meta logo could use some improvement.

Comment: @Pekka - if the currently accepted answer could get accepted, that would be just awesome.

Comment: @Adam yeah. Altough I like squillman's suggestion too - as a *homage* to the old, weird days of Meta.

Comment: Perhaps a more distinguished logo would help reduce the number of people who mistake this for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Hand drawn logos already imply beta sites. It's just unsuitable for Meta (notice the 1 character difference?)

Comment: @Daniel nah. Meta is special.

Comment: I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym (needs something like that)

Comment: We need this. One of the hand drawn ones would be my favourite. Can we *please* have it when the big Meta split comes?

Comment: @Pekka - you're just not giving up :)  -- I'm pretty sure Shog's a bit exhausted from this past week, but hey, maybe this'll be a fun thing for him to look at

Comment: @Adam yeah! Plus the bounty is running for 7 days, so plenty of time to recharge the batteries and tacking the *really* important stuff after all that rep calculation nonsense. :)

Comment: Needs more cowbell too

Comment: Needs more unicorns. And waffels.

Comment: This is hilarious.  How in the world is a question which pertains only and specifically to the "Meta" site supposed to be posted anywhere if you must go to the specific site where your question applies rather than posting on Meta?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It doesn't really fit in, but I think it's pretty meta:

[image: new meta logo, large] 
[image: meta with new logo applied]

Comment: Wow! Good idea! It reminds me of Escher pictures. 

If the topmost element of the topmost stack could "morph" back to the orignal red stack container it would be awesome!

Comment: ... And adding another dimension is a way to go "Meta"...

Comment: This is soooo cool. When can we expect this to be  implemented? :)

Comment: more recursion needed!

Comment: Your graphic design skills are amazing.

Comment: This looks more like Area 51 to me, which generates new Stack sites.

Comment: Super cool... but it would be a disaster as a favicon.

Comment: First of all, was that made in Blender? Second,  @RichardJPLeGuen the favicon can be kept, and the icon changes.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS Yes, it's Blender.

Comment: this is really cool

Answer (score 56):

I'm with Adam Rackis on this one (+1 btw), only you need to try a bit more:

[image: The real Meta Stakoverflow logo]

Comment: +1, though I do prefer my more minimalist version :)

Comment: Ohhhhhhh - you free-handed the logo too - I almost lost some Dr Pepper upon seeing that.

Comment: Well, Dr Pepper. What's the worst that could happen..?

Answer (score 37):

The meta section is about improving stackoverflow and making it better, and that could be represented in the logo. If the logo starts off as a sketch and is improved along the way, ending in a more "finished" state, like the real logo.

I'm not an expert at drawing but here's an example:

[image]

Comment: I actually *really* like this. Brilliant!

Comment: I really like this one :P How about posting some variations too?

Comment: @Lix - Did this during the coffee break to show the `Sketch -> Finished` idea I had. If it gets popular I'll do some more for sure =)

Comment: I think this looks awesome, but it would be easy to confuse with the original SO... maybe if the first part of the logo were even more roughly sketched?

Comment: Wow! I really love this! This would also solve the [alignment problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181340/logo-is-slightly-misaligned/181350?noredirect=1#181350).  To the mods, can we please use this?

Comment: Any luck with other sites?

Answer (score 32):

The current logo is certainly lacking sufficient waffleage.

[image: New MSO Logo]

Comment: And I want a T-Shirt with this one.

Comment: Is that blood or syrup?

Comment: @Dexter: depends on the post

Comment: Love it! You get one upvote from me for this!

Answer (score 28):

Your first proposition makes me think of this:

[image: metal spring]

Well, it would sure represent Meta better in its true purpose: give an [originally serious thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slinky#Creation) to people, so they can play with it endlessly.

Comment: Did a slinky ever have any serious purpose then?

Comment: @Arjan - From the story of its creation (see edited link in anwser), it was originally a serious engineer experiment (something supposed to "support and stabilize sensitive instruments aboard ships in rough seas"), which turned out to be something funny. Exactly like Meta, in fact. Originally to report bugs, and discuss on a high level about the trilogy... And finally filled with waffles, freehand circles and unicorns.

Comment: you are forgetting Icelandic Fridays!

Comment: Your answer (which is a silly response to a potentially vaguely semi-serious question) is reenforced by the fact that it's the highest voted. +1 for not answering the question and diverting the subject to slinkys.

Comment: @Length - I object! My post is actually answering the question "What about something like that instead", as it contains an opinion about one of the propositions. The fact that you feel diverted is only a vicious effect of the slinky, crawling through your child memories.

Answer (score 23):

What about unicorn?

[image: meta unicorn logo]

:)

Answer (score 19):

The current answers are trying a bit too hard.  I think we should keep the original logo, but add some freehand!

[image]

Comment: This is *very* intriguing. I think it's becoming my new favourite.

Comment: I want this. I'd spend 20k of my Unicorn dollars to get this implemented.

Comment: @Pekka - well, when you're [in charge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121540/155403) you can implement it yourself :)

Comment: yeah man! This one will be my top priority. :)

Answer (score 17):

Hrm.  A stackoverflow occurs when another function is called and its variables overwrite beyond the end of the stack, possibly onto other important data.

So if we abstract that out another level...

Hrm.  I shall have to ponder this further.  Currently the only thing I can think of is the error message that occurs when an error message can't be displayed due to a problem with the error message handler.

That's hard to realize in a simple logo though...

How about:

### Core dump

- It's an error that occurs in an error (ie, an error on stack overflow may result in a core dump)
- Can be realized as a simple logo
- Also represents a significant amount of knowledge - it's essentially taking the brain state of the computer and dropping it to disk so it can be dissected.

All of the above really do describe what meta is all about, and it's a nice, catchy idiom.

I'm thinking something along the lines of this for logo:

[image: Logo for core dump - box with gear inside, red arrow suggesting the gear is removed from the box downward - falling out of the box]

The SO font should be used, and the graphic itself isn't great, but it gives the general idea.

Comment: Take the errors causing errors idea far enough and you've got yourself a kernel panic or BSOD, the latter is recognisable enough a small version would do.

Comment: Oooh, Core Dump!  It's perfect for meta stack overflow discussion!

Comment: Thanks @Phoshi - your comment triggered what I was trying to get at...

Comment: So should the new logo be a bomb, then?  Or maybe a trash can.  That would make the *"Meta is not your trash can"* comments *very* ironic.

Comment: But doesn't "dump" carry unmanageable/unwanted connotation?

Comment: I'm seeing lots of logo and double-entendre posisbilities in "core dump". :D

Comment: Oooh, Core Dump! I say we vote for this, we can achieve independence!

Comment: I think it needs a freehand arrow.

Comment: @Aarobot - I had to freehand the arrow in pixel editing mode.  Does that count?

Comment: Only if you made the whole arrow without ever releasing the mouse button, and I *don't* believe your mousing is that accurate.

Answer (score 16):

Needs more freehand circles!

[image: Freehandcirclified]

Comment: [more freehand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120312/165773) needed - but yes, [with circles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PTCEd.png)

Answer (score 8):

@Adam Davis posted:

> Currently the only thing I can think of is the error message that
> occurs when an error message can't be displayed due to a problem with
> the error message handler

Which made me immediately think of this

[image]

Hmm, hows that for a logo!

Answer (score 2):

Another idea: [**Escher hands**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/ba/DrawingHands.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

I'm rubbish at graphics, but I would suggest some metasymbol, like "::="

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more beer-oriented logo?

[image: meta beer logo (Ethiopian)]

Comment: Yeah, see? Y'all down voted this, but now we actually _have_ a meta.beer site. So Pthbbbbbbbbbbbbbb :P