# Logo is slightly misaligned

Tags: discussion, design, logo

Am I the only one who feels like the logo is slightly misaligned? I think the first angled bar should be moved a little bit to the right, so that both corners are aligned. *(pink)*

I also found out that the padding between the container and the first bar is uneven as well. *(blue)*

[image]

Don't get me wrong, I love the concept of the logo, but I feel that it's a little bit off. Did anyone else notice this?

Comment: Which logo? For what site? Where is the image / screen capture that illustrates the issue?

Comment: I'll add the information, one sec please. Sorry ;)

Comment: Both the meta and Stack Overflow icons look a bit skewed to me. A wise man once said that that was [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: Edit: Added the logo with guidelines indicating the problem.

Comment: Maybe that IS the overflow?

Comment: My OCD sense is tingling

Comment: At time of writing, the current logo is in an SVG spritesheet at https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=438582dc9e27 .  As far as I can tell, after zooming in a long way, the leftmost points of the bottom two bars are vertically aligned.  So I guess that perhaps they fixed this at some point in the last five years.

Answer (score 5):

### Once you see it, you can never unsee it.

This is how it should be :

[image]

The meta seems less worst than the main site's. But the explanation is quite simple. It's the color used. If you take a look at this picture

[image]

You can see that the misalignment looks worst on the Main logo than on the Meta logo.
If you zoom the logos 1 and 2 and look at the second bar, you can see that the both bars have 3 pixels of shading around the main color.

The thing is the meta one is gray so the last shading pixel is light gray and is barely visible when zoomed out. Which is why you don't see the last pixels on the left and therefore, see it more centered.

On picture 2, the last pixels of shading is light brown which will still render correctly on a white background.

Take a look pictures 3 and 4. I simply took the Main site colors with the meta shading. Doesn't it look a little more centered ?

Still, thanks to you, my OCD will be killing me everytime I see the main site's logo. Please fix it.

Comment: Reminded me of [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wy52c.png) image [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/46278/212576)

Comment: This whole situation *so* reminds me of this [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/1015/).

Comment: @hjpotter92 Whoa nice one never seen it before.

Comment: Anyways, a good designer should be able to render this correctly. (Moving it around in Illustrator until it looks good or [subpixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) rendering somehow maybe?)

Answer (score 4):

I recently ordered [Jeff Atwood (Coding Horror) stickers](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/coding-horror-stickers.html) and I was glad that he included some other random stickers, including a Stack Overflow one. I can confirm that the two problems outlined here are not present in this sticker:

[image: SO sticker]

So, basically, it's fixed "upstream". Which could mean that it's a problem exporting the logo in case it is in SVG, that the SO logo has not been updated for quite a while or that is a personal fix only for the stickers.