# META logo's last letter got its right leg blunted

Tags: bug, design, meta, logo

The most bottom-right part of "A" in the META logo became blunted. While the left leg has a sharp end.

[image]

Comment: Considering this isn't noticeable without zooming to 1000%, I'm not sure this is needed.

Comment: @blue it is *very* noticable. Did you expect me to browse meta  with 1000% zoom?

Comment: Do you always browse the Internet with an electron microscope?

Comment: @Tim No, I am not going to inspect pixel construction :D

Comment: The shade of red you have used to paint your hand-drawn circles is wrong.

Comment: I don't care about barely noticeable issues around the sites which need a keen eye/zoom to see. *However* I've seen very similar and even less important/less noticeable problems asked here on MSE with a handful of upvotes. Sometimes more upvotes than this has downvotes. So this being downvoted so heavily just makes no sense. It is matter of fact, accurately, without doubt a real and live "issue". So the downvotes are unjustified. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198821/why-is-one-stack-piece-in-the-stack-overflow-logo-slightly-off  It's declared by OP as a dupe & has 63 upvotes. meh +1

Comment: @James The down-votes are pretty much comical at this point. Nicael is one of our most .. prolific ... volunteer testers who finds all _sorts_ of things and reports them. That's just people saying _oh come on, really?!_, but I don't think anyone is truly sad that he posted the report. I'm not, I'm quite frankly amazed that he found it.

Comment: @nicael you're right! I haven't seen you for ages... I was beginning to think SE had eradicated all their design bugs...! :P

Comment: How on Earth did you even notice that?  Do you have a perfection script?

Comment: @san but it's not difficult to notice - the right leg looked a bit blunted compared to left, so I zoomed in and found it! The bug!

Comment: Can't say that I notice it, even now when I am looking for it.

Comment: @san wait, even the screenshot doesn't help?..

Comment: Of course, I can see it in the zoomed in screenshot (only due to your freehand scribbling emphasising it), but the one on top of the page, I still don't notice - I do not see the importance of this either.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The bug is cause by the logo being too wide. The `#hlogo a` has `width 150px`. Setting it to `151px` fixes it. For real!

> [image: fixed]

But let's be fair. Who cares?

Comment: +1 for your final sentence

Comment: Wait. I do care! :P

Comment: At least there is someone who cares @nicael. ;)

Comment: Upon learning of an off-by-one, OCD on the design team will very likely lead to this being fixed :P

Comment: Epic, especially the last line!

Comment: Gold badge, served on a silver plate. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! @Sha. And that for a CSS fix. I don't get that much on SO for that. ;)

Comment: Fix? What fix? It's for the spirit of your answer. :-)

Comment: Yeh, you got a Reversal! :) now get another Enlightened :) you need really more badges! I have less rep but far more badges, not good :D